# chat application deploy

Tags: java, deployment, applet, installation, chat

I have created one sample chat application. In that chat application, I used JApplet and front end.

Till now I was testing my application in my desktop. It is working fine. Now I want to deploy my application over any webserver.

Now I have a few questions. Currently I am using Server socket as 8989 in my chatserver. When I was testing the application in my desktop, I used to start the server as stand alone.

1. What are the steps I have to follow when I deploy the application over tomcat or any other web server? Which port the client will listen?
2. How do I start my chat server? I am new to the socket concepts.

Comment: It is better to limit each question to ***one*** question.

Answer (score 0):

when you say you are hosting on the webserver, i believe that its an servlet/jsp based application , which will listen to your requests , in that case the listener will be invoked at the webserver default port either 80 / 8080 (being default). In case you want to change or check , you can go to the TOMCAT_INSTALLATION_DIR/conf/server.xml and check for tag containing the port number for weblistener, and change it to whatever value you feel like.

if thats not the case and you have your own thread which opens a socket for you , you really dont need a webserver, all you need is a host machine which will start the socket listener ( your custom) and then it will listen at the port that you have configured it to be at.

Comment: Hi Akash thanks for the reply., Currently I have not thought of being used of JSP and servlet. I need to embeded my applet inside the jsp or html in order to load the UI.  But my question is how to start my chat server inside the webserver which has all the logic . Can I user the webserver port to listen client requests? Please let me know how to implement.

Comment: Ohh , yes you can use the server socket to listen your requests, and thats what ideally is suggested, but for that case you should communicate using http protocol , what all you have to do is , make a http request to server may be you would like to read Rest Based call , and use separate threads for posting and reading messages, the read would be pull based.

all together if you want to have bare socket communication you might want to have a look at Server Sockets.

Comment: So client socket part will remain same? or should I change that part also? and In server side how do we make the listener class in order to notify all the clients logged? For example. I want to give message to all clients who connected to particular port 8080, by saying that this particular user logged in.

Comment: There are two approaches  1. Normal HTTP Communication :- it would be session less communication where , whenever user sends message , it will be a http call to servlet, for read there will be iterative call to server for reading messages. when u want a message to be sent u simply make an entry to datastore , which will be read by this thread, most of the chats on web work this way, 2. Sockets approach , with recent developments websockets have came into picture, which are pretty similar to sockets but the only difference is that these are defined on the fly using http comm

Comment: Ohh.. thanks for the good information. I did not know the  concept of storing the message entry to the datastore. Thanks for giving that idea.So In this case is it possible to send all logged people? Or say I want only for some specific people. For example,If five people(A,B,C,D,E) have logged in the chat room. Now I want to send message to only B,D. Is it possible to do this kind of functioanlity when I dont use websocket concept?

Comment: okay, Here we have a table (messages(id,senderid,recieverid,message). Every users pull up messages with recieverid=myid. so when i have to send message to two people i add two records to this table one for a and one for b , its irrelevant howmany of them you want to send the message to isnt it?

Comment: Ok. that I understood. But how the two clients will receive? If it is socket programming, server will send message to the all attached client through sockets. But here how can we specify for A client send this message. How can we make differentiate from other client to only A client. This is my doubt. What syntax I should use?

Comment: Its a session less communication , so every client PULLS the messages iteratively instead of bieng pushed in socket mode, this relieves your server not to keep a track of all the connected clients . Actually the clients are in disconnected mode :)

Comment: Hi thanks Akash..for explanining me in a detailed manner. Still some doubts are there.. :)

Comment: Shoot !! am waiting for those

Answer (score 0):

As far as I got it, you're having standalone application as a server, where you handle connections to particular port.

I think there is some confusion that should be clarified.

The very basic question is:
**Why do you need your chat server to be running on the web server?**

This should be clear to you prio to any later steps.
As web server is there basically to handle HTTP/S requests and that's not your case, as far as I got it. As you're probably running socket TCP/UDP communication.

For the web server however your client applet implemnentation could benefit of. If it would be referrend on a simple html page (deployed inside war) it could be simply redistributable to clients via url call in a web browser.

Maybe I'd preffer to use HTTP + JSON commununication, where you could benefit from web server usage (also on the server side) and would not need any other ports than standard ones.

Not sure if it still makes sence to answer your questions as it might be irrelevant for you, but let's see.

Answers to your questions:

- Basically you need war archive (rather than jar one), as that's the one accepted by web servers. once you create it (you need to follow the correct folder/file structure inside) your app could be deployed to web server.

Which port the client will listen? Basically server is the listener here => no client port listening here.

- This depends on your communication implementation decision. If still sticking with TCP/UDP one, I don't think web server would be beneficial here.

Comment: That particular standalone application will be used by different persons across the world. So I would like to host it somewhere.
Currently I made that chat application by using JApplet. Now that applet I will embded inside any jsp or html. 
This was my requiremnt. In order to achieve these steps,I thought of using any webserver for hosting my application. I dont know this 
is the right way or not. But even after deployment, I dont know how listen the my chat server port which listenes all the client requests.
These are the doubts of mine.